# What is the best practice to assign php variable to javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, javascript-framework

I have some code like this

```
  var minAmountPay =  <?php echo $this->chat['Current']['admin'] >= 1 ? 1 : $this->minAmountPay; ?>;
  var userId = <?php echo $this->currentUserId?>;
```

I use ZF and I have a lot of javascript code in my action files. I want to create js-files for each action and do minifications of this files. But I can't create js-file because I have assigning php variable to javascript variable.

Maybe I need to use some javascript framework for this purposes?

Answer (score 3):

Use [data attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).

For example :

HTML :

```
<div id="something" data-minamountpay="<?php echo $this->chat['Current']['admin'] >= 1 ? 1 : $this->minAmountPay; ?>"></div>
```

JS (with jQuery) :

```
var minAmountPay = $('#something').data('minamountpay');
```

Comment: It's less work to directly output the PHP value to the JavaScript variable...

Comment: But you can't cache JS files and you don't separate interactivity from pure HTML.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it. @Stanyer it's less work to not sanitize your database inputs.

Comment: @AmazingDreams true, true - bad outlook on things my side...

Comment: I think I create view-helper which will be generate js-file with variables. I will have something like this $this->jsVars()->add('name', $value);. And after this I can cache files for each values and i don't like that each time jquery will retrieve values from html.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript cannot directly interact with PHP.

This is because JavaScript is client-side, and PHP is server-side.

The only way to do this is as you have - by producing output in PHP which is put into the script.

Answer (score 1):

you can add javascript to your html file by using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var minAmountPay =  <?php echo $this->chat['Current']['admin'] >= 1 ? 1 : $this->minAmountPay; ?>;
var userId = <?php echo $this->currentUserId?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign these values to hidden inputs in your page.

And get the values by input value.

These values are visible to the user either way.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to think about where you're putting those variables. Can you put them in the HTML instead? When I need to do what you are doing I use the HTML 5 data attributes and assign the variables to appropriate places like this:

```
<div id="my-appropriate-div"
    data-min-amount-pay="<?php echo $this->chat['Current']['admin'] >= 1 ? 1 : $this->minAmountPay; ?>"
    data-user-id="<?php echo $this->currentUserId ?>">
```

Then in JavaScript you can access the data thusly:

```
var minAmountPay = $('#my-appropriate-div').data('min-amount-pay');
var userId = $('#my-appropriate-div').data('user-id');
```

Obviously rather than putting them into variables, I just use them directly where needed in my functions.